# Type-hinted object initializer in parent constructor

Tags: typescript, constructor, parent, object-initializers

Is it possible to have a type-hinted object initializer inside a constructor on a parent class? Ex:

```
class Model {
    modelField: string;
    constructor(initializer: SomeSpecialType){
        Object.assign(this, initializer);
    }
}

class User extends Model{
    email: string;
}

const user = new User({
    email: '...' // only get type hints for the email property
})
```

I know it is possible using a static method:

```
class Model{
    someField: string;
    static new<T extends Model>(this: new() => T, data: Omit<T, keyof Model>) {
        return Object.assign(new this, data);
    }
}

const user = User.new({
    email: 'some email'
})
```

I tried to use the same parameters inside the constructor but TS is telling me that the `this` keyword cannot be used in a `constructor` not generics can be used there.

Comment: amazing question. Sad that there is no answer yet

Comment: I think Typescript doesn't support this right now. Maybe the team will add this feature in the future. Who knows...